# Total sum of database field value with where condition in Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I  table **student_atendence** table fields are (id ,studid,attendence).

This is my table **student_atendence**:

**studid    attendence**

```
28          1       
31          1       
32          1   
28          1   
31          1   
32          1   
28          1   
31          1   
32          1   
28          1   
31          0   
32          1   
28          0   
31          1   
32          1   
28          1   
31          1   
32          0   
28          1   
31          1   
32          0
```

I want result like this

```
id      studid     total 1's     total 0's   

1         28        6              1

2        31         6              1

3        32         5              2
```

How can I get the total count of attendence =1 and attendence=0 of each students separately?

Eg: 28 -  6 (total no.of 1 s) and 1(total o.of 0 s), 31 -  6 (total no.of 1 s) and 1(total o.of 0 s), 32 -  5 (total no.of 1 s) and 2(total o.of 0 s).

My controller code :

```
foreach($students as $student){
        $cunt1 = DB::table($wys_attendence_table)
                    ->where('studid',$student->id)
                  ->where('amonth',$amonth)
                ->where('ayear',$ayear)
                ->where('attendence','=',1)
                 ->count();
       $cunt0 = DB::table($wys_attendence_table)
                 ->where('studid',$student->id)
                  ->where('amonth',$amonth)
                ->where('ayear',$ayear)
                ->where('attendence','=',0)
                 ->count();
                 //var_dump($cunt1);
                //var_dump($cunt0);
        }
```

My view page:

```
@foreach($stud_attend as $stud_attends)
    @if($student->id == $stud_attends->studid)
        @if($stud_attends->attendence == 1)
            <td>
                <font color="green" size="3">p</font>
            </td>
        @elseif($stud_attends->attendence == 0)
            <td>
                <font color="red" size="3">a</font>
            </td>
        @endif
        <td>{{ $cunt1 }}</td>
        <td>{{ $cunt0 }}</td>
    @endif
@endforeach
```

I get the correct answer from `var_dump($cunt0)`, `var_dump($cunt1)` but it does not work in the view page.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it with conditional counts like this

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9d3c1/2

```
SELECT
  studid,
  sum(attendence = 1) AS `total 1's`,
  sum(attendence = 0) AS `total 0's`
FROM
  student_atendence
GROUP BY
  studid;
```

I am not sure where you want to get that `id` you show in expected results as one studid can have many ids assigned in that table. If you want the smallest one, you can add `min(id) AS id` to select as in http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9d3c1/4 but it has not much real meaning.

I do not have experience with Laravel, but there seems to be a possibility to pass [RAW expressions](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/queries#raw-expressions). Something like (just guessing here):

```
DB::table($wys_attendence_table)
->select(DB::raw('studid, sum(attendence = 1) AS `total1`, sum(attendence = 0) AS `total0`'))
->where('studid',$student->id)
->where('amonth',$amonth)
->where('ayear',$ayear);
```

(I changed the aliases to access it better in an array)

Comment: how to transform this  above  code  " SELECT
  studid,
  sum(attendence = 1) AS `total 1's`,
  sum(attendence = 0) AS `total 0's`
FROM
  student_atendence
GROUP BY
  studid; "                into laravel  db bulider code. i want in laravel code. its mysql code. how to change laravel

Comment: See edit - not sure it is 100% right, but something like this should work. It is supposed to return an array of 3 columns.

Answer (score 0):

You can do with if condition also

select id,studid,sum(if(attendence=1,1,0)) as total1 ,sum(if(attendence=0,1,0)) as total0 from student_atendence group by studid;